# Custom regex word boundary (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a custom word boundary (like `\b`) that also takes words starting or ending with the unicode characters "ÆØÅæøå" into consideration.

Now the only thing I can come up with is this ugly thing

`((?<![\wÆØÅæøå])(?=[\wÆØÅæøå])|(?![\wÆØÅæøå])(?<=[\wÆØÅæøå]))`

Is there a more elegant solution to this? Or is this the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_]) // leading word boundary, similar to \<, [[:<:]] or \m in other flavors
(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])         // trailing word boundary, similar to \>, [[:>:]] or \M
```

Compile the regex with the `u` modifier to enable Unicode category classes.

The `(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])` is a negative lookbehind that matches a location not immediately preceded with a letter followed with zero or more diacritic marks or a digit or an underscore.

The `(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])` is a negative lookahead that matches a location not immediately followed with a letter, digit or an underscore.